# how to find ESXi server ip address from an vm instance

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am working on a project where I need to figure out the ip address of an ESXi server .

vcenter 'A' has 6 ESXi servers (B,C,D,E,F,G). I am using a vm instance which is configured in D. I get user inputs from UI about A (Vcenter ip address) and the vm instance ip address, user id, password. Need to figure out the ESXi server IP Address (D) to proceed further. Any pointer to this would be really appreciated !

Comment: Wow, terribly written question - very hard to follow. So you have a vCenter with all of your hosts in and you want to know the IP address of one of them - is that right? If that's the case then just nslookup the hostname as displayed in vCenter. If you're after something else you're going to have to learn to write.

Answer (score 1):

The server could have several IP-addresses. Following the comment of "Chopper3", you will probably see IP address of the management interface of the ESXi.

To see all network adapters and their configuration (including IP-addresses), you should find the corresponding ESXi host in vSphere Web Client (Home --> Hosts and Clusters, then locate needed server). Then go to Manage --> Networking. There you could see all cards (Physical adapters), switches (Virtual switches) and adapters with IP-addresses (VMkernel adapters) and even routing table/gataways/etc. (TCP/IP configuration).

If you do not have access to the vCenter, and do not know anything about your ESXi server (hostname, etc.), this could be hard to figure out, since network is also virtualised in the VMware environment, and from the VM you do not have any good opportunities to find out anything about the configuration of the host. E.g., if Distributed switches are used, your VM could even be connected to network through adapter on another ESXi server in the vCenter, and not one the VM is running on.